# Using Cauchy's Convergence Criterion to prove divergence of series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

**Problem:**

Using Cauchy's Convergence Criterion I have to prove that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}$$
diverges.

**Attempt:**

Cauchy's Convergence Criterion:

$\forall \epsilon \gt 0  \, \, \exists$ an integer $N$ s.t $|a_n + a_{n+1} + ... + a_{m}| \lt \epsilon$ if $m\ge n \gt N$.

So I have to prove that for any $\epsilon \le |a_n + a_{n+1} + ... + a_{m}| $ . But I am completely stuck here. Any guidance will be much appreaciated.

<s>**EDIT**: Further Attempt</s>

Consider

$$|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}}+ ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{m(m+1)}}|$$

Which is less or equal to $\frac{1}{n+1}$, so we get:

$$|\frac{1}{n+1}|\le|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}}+ ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{m(m+1)}}|$$
$$\downarrow$$
So if $\epsilon \gt 0$ we can choose $N$ so that
$$|\frac{1}{N+1}| \ge \epsilon$$

Thus proving that the series diverges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint :**
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}} \geq \frac{1}{n+1}$$

and now, you can use the Cauchy criterion to prove that the harmonic series $\sum \frac{1}{n+1}$ diverges.

Comment: Sorry for the stupidity. How would one proceed to prove that $\sum \frac{1}{n+1}$ diverges explicitly using **the Cauchy criterion**?

Comment: Well, how do you prove that the harmonic series diverges ? The most elementary way is to see that, for $$H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$$ one has $$H_{2^{n+1}}-H_{2^n} \geq \frac{1}{2}$$ and so $(H_n)$ is not Cauchy.

Comment: Added a further attempt, does it look correct?

Comment: @BobPen You attempt does not mean anything, unfortunately... Begin by trying to prove, as I hinted you in the previous comment, that $\sum 1/n$ diverges using Cauchy criterion.

Comment: I am having trouble proving divergence of $\sum 1/n$ using Cauchy Criterion. Do you have the possibility to show this?

Comment: I already showed the different steps in my comment ! Where are you stuck ?

Comment: I figured it out. Had to read more about the criterion to understand it first. Thank you.